# What conditions are needed for squid Monster Spawner block to work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a Monster Spawner block that has been set to spawn squids. How do I have to place it for it to spawn them?

Comment: Is this a Monster Spawner block that has been hacked to spawn squids? Or are you trying to create a pool that will naturally spawn squids? This would be clearer if you told us what you have already tried. (Even better would be a screenshot of what you've tried.)

Comment: I got a monster spawner block

Comment: You *probably* need to put it underwater. Passive mob spawners still need the same conditions for spawning as if they spawned normally: grass for animals, water for squid. I haven't tested this though, so if someone does and it works, please post it as an answer.

Comment: ok ill try it thx

Answer (score 4):

A spawner will attempt to spawn mobs at random locations inside a cuboid with side lengths of 9 blocks in both horizontal directions and a height of 3 blocks.

Thank you to IQAndreas for this additional information:

> Note that those "cuboid" restrictions can be changed with map editors such as MCEdit, allowing you to much more heavily customize where and with what properties squids will spawn.

---

For the mob to actually spawn, this randomly chosen location must meet certain criteria, otherwise no mob is spawned at this location.

The criteria for squids are:

- The squid must not collide with other entities. It can, however, spawn inside a block.
- The location must be in layer 46-62.

If there is at least one block inside that cuboid that meets these criteria, it is possible for squids to spawn.

Reference: [Minecraftwiki article "Monster Spawner"](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawner#Detailed_spawning_algorithm)

Comment: Note that those "cuboid" restrictions can be changed with map editors such as MCEdit, allowing you to much more heavily customize where and with what properties squids will spawn.

Answer (score 0):

Squid Spawners work for me, they spawn.  But very shortly after they start to die, because I put them on land.  All the Spawners work, you need to stand about 10-15 blocks away for it to work.  Well that's what works for me.  Hope this helped.